# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, bower, materialize

I've searched high and low for an answer to this, but every instance of this problem seems to be fairly unique.  Perhaps a couple extra sets of eyes can help shed some light on this.

I'm receiving an error in my console:

> app.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

My angular application is working just fine, but this error continues to persist despite what I do.  I think the error came about when I restructured my code to follow a style guide written by Todd Motto.  In any event, my app.js is as follows:

```
(function() {

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partial/main'
        })
        .when('/assignment/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partial/assignment',
            controller: 'SubmissionController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.materialize', 'ngAnimate'])
    .config(config);

})();
```

My dependencies are as follows:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="myApp")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0")

    title= title    

    link(rel='icon', type='image/png', href='favicon.ico')

    // bower:css
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css')
    // endbower

    script(src='js/app.js') styles
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/app.css") 
    link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet")

  body(ng-controller="AssignmentController")
    block content 

    //- lib js
    // bower:js
    script(src='../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/Materialize/bin/materialize.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular-materialize/src/angular-materialize.js')
    // endbower  

    //- app js 
    script(src='js/app.js')
    script(src='js/controllers.js')
    script(src='js/services.js')
    script(src='js/directives.js')        
    script(src='//localhost:35729/livereload.js')
```

Through trial and error I've omitted each dependency one at a time.  I've tried rearranging the order in which each dependency is loaded and I've even tried rearranging the order in which each of my application specific files are listed, but to no avail.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you sure Angular is loading? Looks like it isn't loading.

Comment: @LéoLam Through my console I was able to confirm that each and every dependency is loading by viewing the source and seeing there are no 500 or 404 errors.  In addition to that, my app is working just fine, but this error continues to persist.

Comment: Which line of code in your app is the error being thrown from?

Comment: @mindparse app.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ app.js:22 (anonymous function) @ app.js:27

----> angular
            .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.materialize', 'ngAnimate'])
           .config(config);

Comment: Well you're loading app.js twice: once in the head before Angular has been loaded, and second time in the body after Angular. The first script throws an error but the app works because it runs without error the second time it's loaded.

Comment: Oh wow!  Good eye @Juhana I'm going to blame grunt for that one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JJJ

"Well you're loading app.js twice: once in the head before Angular has been loaded, and second time in the body after Angular. The first script throws an error but the app works because it runs without error the second time it's loaded:"

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="myApp")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0")

    title= title    

    link(rel='icon', type='image/png', href='favicon.ico')

    // bower:css
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css')
    // endbower

    // - [FIX] removed: script(src='js/app.js')         
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/app.css") 
    link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet")

  body(ng-controller="AssignmentController")
    block content 

    //- lib js
    // bower:js
    script(src='../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular/angular.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/Materialize/bin/materialize.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js')
    script(src='../bower_components/angular-materialize/src/angular-materialize.js')
    // endbower  

    //- app js 
    script(src='js/app.js')
    script(src='js/controllers.js')
    script(src='js/services.js')
    script(src='js/directives.js')        
    script(src='//localhost:35729/livereload.js')
```